# Web Socket en PHP no se conecta desde otra computadora

Tags: php, websocket

Tengo un problema con un WebSocket,

estoy usando el siguiente código para conectar un servicio de WebSocket, y funciona correctamente mientras ejecute la pagina en el mismo servidor, pero al momento de accederla desde otra computadora de la red no se puede conectar al servicio, ya cambie la ip local a la ip de la intranet y no funciona, entonces cambie la ip a un rango y funciona otra vez solo localmente pero no desde otra computadora, les envió el código donde creo que esta el problema.

```
// start the server
$Server = new PHPWebSocket();
$Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');
$Server->bind('open', 'wsOnOpen');
$Server->bind('close', 'wsOnClose');
// for other computers to connect, you will probably need to change this to your LAN IP or external IP,
// alternatively use: gethostbyaddr(gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
$Server->wsStartServer('0.0.0.0', 9300);
```

No se si sea problema de permisos, o que otra cosa pueda estar pasando de antemano les agradezco mucho su ayuda.

PD. Ya revise en las preguntas hechas en esta pagina, e implemente esas soluciones, pero al menos en mi caso no funcionan.